# Views managing fields with style in Drupal7

Tags: views, theming

i have created a view

having three fields   as image , title and  body

i want to show image on left and  on right hand side title and below title body .

i don't want to customize view template file. is there is any option so i will get desired results .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do this using css.

Comment: i don't want to use css .

Comment: is there any specific reason you dont want to use css?

Comment: yeah.  i did this going to upload answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exculde From display first and second field  and in third field  use rewrite output  something like this

```
<div>
<div style='float:left'>[field_movie_image]</div>
<div style='float:left'>[title] [body] </div>
</div>
```

it is working for me. itself in a view

Comment: I thought you said without using css and without using style. :-)

Comment: i want to do within view only

Comment: It is always better to do something like this in css unless you have a very specific reason to do so. Any if this works for you well and good :-)